# Prove that,if $n$ is an integer, then $n^2 + 15n = 1$ is odd

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I'm proving this by cases and have so far:

*Case* 1:

> Say $n$ is an even integer. Since $n$ is even, then $n=2m$ for some
>   integer $m$. So $n^2-n+5 = (2m)^2-2m+5 = 4m^2-2m+5 = 2(2m^2-m)+5$....

*Case* 2:

> Say $n$ is an odd integer. Since $n$ is odd, then $n=2x+1$ for some
>   integer $x$. So $n^2-n+5 = (2x+1)^2-(2x+1)+5 = 4x^2+2x+5$....

How can I manipulate the equation in each case to show that is is odd?

Comment: Your title doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You work seems to be in trying to prove that $n^2-n+5$ is always odd.  Your title reads "...then $n^2+15n=1$ is odd" which of course makes no sense since an equation cannot be "even" or "odd" which does not match your attempts.

Comment: Note $2(2m^2-m)+5 = 2(2m^2-m+2) + 1$ which is $2$ times an integer plus $1$, exactly the format a number should be in order to be called odd.  Similar manipulation can be done for the second.

Comment: Hint: even+odd results in even.

Comment: I'm required to prove it with two cases: n is even and n is odd.

Comment: The others are trying to convince you that, when $n$ is an integer, $n^2 + 15 n$ must be even. As a result, the equation $n^2 + 15 n = 1$ does not have any integer solutions. The two cases must be to show $n(n+15)$ is even when $n$ is an integer.

Comment: "I'm required to prove it with two cases"  You are required to prove *what* with two cases.  You have never told us in the body of the post what you are trying to prove.  You title is completely different (and doesn't make any sense).

Comment: If $n^2 + 15n = 1$ then the there are only two possible values than $n$ can be.  And neither of them can be integers.  If $n$ is an integer than $n^2 + 15n = n(n+15)$ and $n$ and $n+15$ are two different integers.  The only pair of integers that multiply to $1$ are $(1,1)$ and $(-1, -1)$.  But you can' t have *both* $n$ and $n+15$ equal to $1$ or $-1$.

Comment: Please fix the post, it does not make sense to talk about equation being odd. Numbers can be odd.

Answer (score 2):

If $n = 2m$ is even then you have $n^2 -n + 5 =2(2m^2 -m) + 5$.  And that is $2(2m^2 - m) + 4 + 1 = 2(2m^2 - m +2) + 1$.  Which is odd.

If $n = 2x + 1$ is odd then you have $n^2 - n + 5 = 4x^2 +2x + 5$.  And that is $2(x^2 + x) + 5 = 2(x^2 +x) + 4 + 1 = 2(x^2 + x + 2) + 1$.  Which is odd.

===

It might be better to point out:

$odd*odd = odd$ and $odd*even = even$ and $even*even = even$ and $odd \pm odd = even$ and $even \pm even = even$ and $even \pm odd = odd$.  (If you don't know that then prove that to yourself right now.)

Then

Case 1: $n$ is even.  So $n^2$ is even.  And $n$ is even.  So $n^2 - n$ is even.  And $5$ is odd.  So $n^2 - n + 5$ is odd.

Case 2: $n$ is odd.  So $n^2$ is odd.  And $n$ is odd.  So $n^2 - n$ is even.  And $5$ is odd.  So $n^2 - n + 5$ is odd.

=====

By the way.  In your body you *never* actually *said* that you were trying to prove $n^2 - n + 5$ is odd.

And in your title you say you are trying to prove "$n^2 +15n =1$ is odd." This makes no sense.  $n^2 + 15n =1$ is an equation.  An equation is a sentence.  A sentence is not a number.  A sentence can not be odd.  "prove $n^2 + 15n = 1$ is odd" makes as much sense as "Prove 'Dolphins eat fish' is gray".  "Dolphins eat fish" can't be any color.

Also if $n$ is an integer then $n + 15$ is an integer.  So if $n^2 +15n = n(n+15) = 1$ then the only pair of integers that multiply to $1$ is $1*1$ and $-1*-1$.  So either $n = 1$ and $n+15 = 1$.  Or $n = -1$ and $n+15 = -1$.  Both of those are impossible.

ALSO.... if $n$ is even then $n^2$ is even and $15n$ is even and $n^2 + 15n$ is even.  So $n^2 +15n = 1$ is not possible if $n$ is even because $1$ is odd.  If $n$ is odd then $n^2$ is odd and $15n$ is odd and $n^2 +15n$ is even.  So $n^2 + 15n = 1$ is not possible if $n$ is odd because $1$ is odd.  So $n^2 + 15n = 1$ is impossible if $n$ is even or odd.  So if $n$ is an integer then $n^2 + 15n \ne 1$.  And if $n^2 + 15n = 1$ then $n$ is not an integer.

If you know the quadratic equation then

$n^2 + 15n = 1$ means $n^2 + 15n - 1= 0$ means $n = \frac {-15 \pm \sqrt{15^2 -4(-1)}}2 = \frac {-15 \pm \sqrt {229}}2$ where are not integers.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach is by induction. Let $$P(n) : n^2-n+5 = 2m+1 \text { for some } m\in\mathbb{Z}.$$
$P(0)$ is true since $0^2-0+5=5$, which is odd.

Since we are considering both positive and negative integers we need to show that $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ and $P(n)\implies P(n-1)$.

If $P(n)$ holds, we have
\begin{align}
(n+1)^2-(n+1)+5&=n^2+2n+1-n-1+5\\
&= (n^2-n+5)+2n,
\end{align}
which is an odd number plus an even number, hence it is odd.

Similarly, we have
\begin{align}
(n-1)^2-(n-1)+5&=n^2-2n+1-n+1+5\\
&=(n^2-n+5)-2n+2\\
&=(n^2-n+5)-2(n-1),
\end{align}
which is an odd number minus an even number,, hence also odd.

Therefore $n^2-n+5$ is odd for all $n\in\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

This true for every polynomial with following form:

$(2k±1) x^n + (2k_1 ±1) x ^m + . . . +1$

If the number of terms is odd, because when the number of terms having factor x is even the sum of these terms will be even.This is clear when $x = 2p ±1$ is, in fact we have:

$x^ q=(2p ±1)^q= 2m ±1$

$c= 2k ±1$

$c \times x^q= 2t ±1$

That is any power of an odd number is odd, the results will also be odd if the coefficient c is odd. Now when the number of terms of odd terms is even the sum of them will also be even.It is far clear when x is even, the sum of terms is always even.

Here the number of terms is 3 and coefficients of x  are 1 and 15.